# How is detox code inserted into the app bundle

Tags: react-native, detox

I use detox to run e2e tests on react native.

This [artcile](https://hackernoon.com/detox-gray-box-end-to-end-testing-framework-for-mobile-apps-196ccd9564ce) written by one of the people working on detox says

> Gray box essentially uses a piece of code that is planted in the app, it can help us see what’s going on inside.

My question is, how does that happen? Looking at the [docs](https://github.com/wix/detox/blob/master/docs/APIRef.Configuration.md#build-configuration) the command used for `detox build` is

> `xcodebuild -project ios/YourProject.xcodeproj -scheme YourProject -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ios/build`

No detox-specific mention to be seen there.

Also, the docs [state here](https://github.com/wix/detox/blob/master/docs/APIRef.Configuration.md#device-configuration) that the build command is optional and that

> You can also choose not to use it and provide a compiled app by yourself.

Well, how do I do that? How do I inject detox / make sure detox is not injected into my app? If I download compiled app from my CI server it does not work with detox (not surprisingly since the detox code is not planted into the app). But if I use the `detox build` command (which seem to just run whatever the `build` command in the config specifies), the tests work. There seems to be some "magic" happening which is not understandable for a newcomer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's magic!

Well, actually it isn't. The build step *is* completely optional, and as stated in the documentation, Detox works with any valid app.

In order to load Detox, we tell the dynamic linker to load it using the [`DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dyld.1.html) environment variable. So it only loads Detox when you run `detox test` from the command line.

This is easy on the simulator as it has access to your Mac's file system. Once we implement support for testing on actual hardware devices, we will still use that environment variable, but we will have to inject it inside your IPA file directly.

Comment: so that means I should not need to run the `detox build` command and I should be able to use the output of CI. CI gives me a xcarchive file, which contains an .app file (among other things) - can you confirm detox should work with that (it doesn't work out of the box, so it seems I'll have to do some debugging, I just wanna be sure if I'm taking the right direction). Thanks!

Comment: Xcarchive is usually arm64 architecture, while the simulator is x86_64.

Comment: As long as your CI can build an .app with x86_64 arch (iphonesimulatoros SDK), it will be possible to use with Detox. If my answer has answered your question, please mark it so.